# Spring Boot Clients Not Deregistered from Spring Boot Admin when Spring Boot Instance Stopped

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-admin

We have Spring Boot Admin Version-2.0.3 and corresponding Client Version.

Our spring boot instances are deployed to Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Everything works great, until we deploy a new version of a spring boot instance.  A new internal url is generated for the instance, and get registered to admin. But it didn't deregister the removed instance from the admin.

So it leaves spring boot admin in an inconsistent state. such as:

[image]

how can I make the registered instance deregister itself when it gets destryed.

I have tried setting:

```
spring.boot.admin.client.auto-deregistration = true
```

But it doesn't work as hoped.

Answer (score 0):

The setting `auto-deregistration=true` causes your client application to send a http delete call to the server on endpoint `/instances/{id}`. Csrf checking must be disabled for this endpoint as well on the server. This configuration was missing in the sample securityconfiguration in the spring boot admin documentation. ( See https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1251 )
To fix this, replace

```
.csrf()
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
.ignoringAntMatchers(adminContextPath + "/instances", adminContextPath + "/actuator/**");
```

With

```
.csrf()
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
.ignoringRequestMatchers(
    new AntPathRequestMatcher(adminContextPath + "/instances", HttpMethod.POST.toString()),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher(adminContextPath + "/instances/*", HttpMethod.DELETE.toString()),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher(adminContextPath + "/actuator/**")
);
```